# Can a UK visa and BRP card associated with an expired passport be used for re-entry into the UK alongside a valid passport issued by another country?

Tags: uk, uk-residents

My UK Tier 2 visa is on an expired passport, and my BRP card is tied to that visa. I am planning on traveling out of the UK soon, and I am wondering if I can use the expired passport with the valid visa, the BRP card, and a valid passport issued by a different country (from that of the expired passport) to re-enter the UK? The UKVI website seems to suggest that this is allowed in general, but there are no clarifications regarding passports from different countries (the US seems to disallow that case, for example).

Comment: Why is this being flagged as off topic? It's still about traveling, even though David is an expat!

Comment: The US also doesn't issue residence permits to nonimmigrant workers (i.e., analogous to someone on a tier 2 visa); the only document such a person can use to enter the US is a visa. On the other hand, US permanent residents do not even require a passport to enter the US, so once someone has permanent residence, their nationality is of little importance. I suspect that the same is probably true of someone with ILR in the UK, but I do not know about your case, I'm afraid.

Comment: According to https://www.gov.uk/change-circumstances-visa-brp you need to obtain a new BRP if you change your nationality.  That's seemingly not what you've done, but it does imply you might have issues trying to enter with a different passport - but having the old passport may be enough to avoid any issues.

Comment: @Doc it's possible that there has been no change in nationality here (indeed, it's probable, since most countries allow people to acquire their nationality only if they reside in the country).  But even if there has been, I suspect that the real trigger is that the existing nationality has become invalid.  That is, someone who used the passport of country A to get a BRP needs to get a new BRP if they cease to be a national of country A.  Adding another nationality probably does not actually necessitate applying for a new BRP.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best idea is to phone Border Force at your UK intended airport of arrival. There are a couple of issues here:
- does the change of nationality trigger the 'change of circumstances'? 
- does your new nationality require 'Entry Clearance' or a Visa for the airline to carry you?

Comment: I don't think there's any suggestion here that the passport is for a newly acquired nationality.

Comment: OP says " valid passport issued by a different country" - I took to mean new nationality alongside passport from previous nationality linked to BRP. Perhaps OP could clarify - I may have grasped the wrong end of the stick firmly with both hands!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Another possibility is of course that David already had that other nationality before applying for the BRP, in which case one of the two issues you raise does not apply, but the other one is still relevant.  It would be perhaps more helpful to add a paragraph or so explaining *why* each issue is relevant (or might be).

Comment: Thank's phoog, I think I'll wait for OP to respond so I can clarify my concerns with more facts on which to expand my reply. As I said, I may have misunderstood.